# PhoneNumber is not a member of PublishRequest aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

I declared new PublishRequest and tried to declare PhoneNumber for it but it gives me error saying PhoneNumber is not a member of Publish Request.

I am new at aws.

Comment: This question needs an [mcve]. Would you edit the post to show what code you have, and what specific AWS technology you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=250183&tstart=0

PhoneNumber property was added in version 3.1.1.0 of AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService..."

Can you make sure your AWS SDK is with this version or higher

Comment: Thank you so so much. I got the latest version and it worked.

Comment: sure, don't forget to vote for the answer, please :)